# ffmpeg doesn't seem to be working with multiple audio streams correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having an issue with ffmpeg 3.2.2; ordinarily I ask it to make an MP4 video file with 2 audio streams. The command line looks like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe
-rtbufsize 256M 
-f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -thread_queue_size 512 
-f dshow -i audio="Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)" 
-f dshow -i audio="Line 3 (Virtual Audio Cable)" 
-map 0:v -map 1:a -map 2:a 
-af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y "c:\temp\2channelvideo.mp4"
```

I've wrapped it for legibility. This once worked fine, but something is wrong lately - it doesnt seem to record any audio, even though I can use other tools like Audacity to record audio from these devices just fine

I'm trying to do some diag on it by dropping the video component and asking ffmpeg to record the two audio devices to two separate files:

```
ffmpeg.exe
-f dshow -i audio="Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)" "c:\temp\line2.mp3" 
-f dshow -i audio="Line 3 (Virtual Audio Cable)" "c:\temp\line3.mp3"
```

ffmpeg's console output looks like:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, dshow, from 'audio=Line 2 (Virtual Audio Cable)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 5935.810000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=Line 3 (Virtual Audio Cable)':
  Duration: N/A, start: 5936.329000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to 'c:\temp\line2.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libmp3lame
Output #1, mp3, to 'c:\temp\line3.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf57.56.100
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
  Stream #0:0 -> #1:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

The problem i'm currently having is that the produced mp3 are identical copies of line 2 only; line 3 audio is not recorded. The last line is of concern; it seems to be saying that stream 0 is being mapped to both output 0 and 1? Do I need a map command for each file also? I thought it would be implicit due to the way i specified the arguments

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I needed to add a `-map x:a` between each source and output file, where x was either 0 or 1 depending on if it was the first or second source..